# I have the following error when using jinja2: TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 553

Tags: python, latex, jinja2

I am trying to create a TEX document from a python code. The inputs are only the title and content, for content I want to iterate through a list containing information of time and then some text as follows:

\hl{time} \ [1cm]
text here

\hl{time} \ [1cm]
text here

The thing is that i have an error about the template:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TemplateSyntaxError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-930ff968e7c6> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 generate_latex_document(template_path, "AUDIENCIA", times_and_text)

6 frames
/content/drive/MyDrive/Con-texto/main.tex in template()
     18 \lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{logo.png}}
     19 \chead{\textbf{Transcripcion de archivo: {{title}} } \break }
---> 20 \rhead{{\small \today} \\ [0.9cm]}
     21 
     22 \fancyfoot{}

TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\\' at 553
```

Here is my template:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, headheight=3cm, footskip=1cm, top=3.5cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=1.5cm, marginparsep=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor, color, soul}
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{225, 225, 225}
\sethlcolor{mygray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{logo.png}}
\chead{\textbf{Transcripcion de archivo: {{title}} } \break }
\rhead{{\small \today} \\ [0.9cm]}

\fancyfoot{} 
\cfoot{{\color{gray} Página \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}}

\begin{document}

{% for item in items %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

\end{document}
```

Here is my code:

```
def make_items(times, paragraphs):
  times_and_text = []

  for i, (time, paragraph) in enumerate(zip(times, paragraphs)):
    start = time["start"]
    end = time["end"]
    times_and_text.append("\hl{%s - %s}" % (start, end) + "\\[1cm]")
    times_and_text.append(paragraph)

  return times_and_text

def generate_latex_document(template_path, title, items):
    # Load the LaTeX template from the file
    template_loader = FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
    env = Environment(loader=template_loader)
    template = env.get_template(template_path)

    # Render the template with the provided data
    latex_content = template.render(title=title, items=items)

    # Write the rendered content to a file
    with open("output.tex", "w") as f:
        f.write(latex_content)
```

The problem is in the "generate_latex_document()" function, I tried to delete that line in latex but It appears the same problem in this line "\cfoot{{\color{gray} Página \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}}".
Any thoughts how I can solve this? thank you in advance!

I tried to delete that line in latex but It appears the same problem in this line "\cfoot{{\color{gray} Página \thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}}".
Any thoughts how I can solve this? thank you in advance!